# Integral involving Cosine function

Tags: integration

What will be the formula for the following:

$$\int_0^\infty \cos(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

well,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos x dx = \lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\alpha} \cos x d x = \lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \left[ \sin x\right]_{x=0}^{\alpha}= \lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \sin \alpha$$

Comment: But i need a finite value for the integration. Is there any process to get a finite value??? Is there any alternative way so that i can integrate it and get a finite value

Comment: Nope, because this limit does not exist

Comment: why the downvote ?